# Changing the apparent focal distance of an object

Tags: optics, vision, glass, lenses

*I'm not completely confident this is the write SE site to post this on, but it seems like the most relevant one.*

I want to make an object (with negligible thickness) that is around one to five centimetres away from the human eye appear around 5 to 6 (infinity) metres away in terms of how the eye's lens needs to focus in order for the object to fall on the focal plane. That is, I want to use an external glass/plastic (fresnel, maybe)? lens to "pre-focus" the object so the eye has to do less work. The object can be at max one centimetre away from the lens, though the less distance between the object and the lens.

Is constructing such a lens possible with modern technology? In a more general sense, how can one calculate what the maximum amount of change in "apparent focal distance" that one can make given a material?

Comment: Bump? Even a comment would help